# JOGL hardware based shadow mapping - computing the texture matrix

Tags: opengl, java, shadows, jogl, shadow-mapping

I am implementing hardware shadow mapping as described [here](http://www.paulsprojects.net/tutorials/smt/smt.html).

I've rendered the scene successfully from the light POV, and loaded the depth buffer of the scene into a texture. This texture has correctly been loaded - I check this by rendering a small thumbnail, as you can see in the screenshot below, upper left corner. The depth of the scene appears to be correct - objects further away are darker, and that are closer to the light are lighter.

However, I run into trouble while rendering the scene from the camera's point of view using the depth texture - the texture on the polygons in the scene is rendered in a weird, nondeterministic fashion, as shown in the screenshot.
I believe I am making an error while computing the texture transformation matrix, but I am unsure where exactly.

Since I have no matrix utilities in JOGL other then the `gl[Load|Mult]Matrix` procedures, I multiply the matrices using them, like this:

```
void calcTextureMatrix() {
  glPushMatrix();

  glLoadIdentity();
  glLoadMatrixf(biasmatrix, 0);
  glMultMatrixf(lightprojmatrix, 0);
  glMultMatrixf(lightviewmatrix, 0);
  glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, shadowtexmatrix, 0);

  glPopMatrix();
}
```

I obtained these matrices by using the `glOrtho` and `gluLookAt` procedures:

```
  glLoadIdentity()
  val wdt = width / 45
  val hgt = height / 45
  glOrtho(wdt, -wdt, -hgt, hgt, -45.0, 45.0)
  glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, lightprojmatrix, 0)

  glLoadIdentity()
  glu.gluLookAt(
    xlook + lightpos._1, ylook + lightpos._2, lightpos._3,
    xlook, ylook, 0.0f,
    0.f, 0.f, 1.0f)
  glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, lightviewmatrix, 0)
```

My bias matrix is:

```
float[] biasmatrix = new float[16] {
  0.5f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f,
  0.f, 0.5f, 0.f, 0.f,
  0.f, 0.f, 0.5f, 0.f,
  0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.f
}
```

After applying the camera projection and view matrices, I do:

```
glTexGeni(GL_S, GL_TEXTURE_GEN_MODE, GL_EYE_LINEAR)
glTexGenfv(GL_S, GL_EYE_PLANE, shadowtexmatrix, 0)
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_GEN_S)
```

for each component.

Does anybody know why the texture is not being rendered correctly?

Thank you.

[image: scene]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiplying the matrices that way does not work.

Instead, using the Java JAMA package for matrices:

```
  import Jama._

  Matrix bi = new Matrix(4, 4);
  Matrix lp = new Matrix(4, 4);
  Matrix lv = new Matrix(4, 4);
  Matrix cv = new Matrix(4, 4);

  // store the float arrays to matrices

  Matrix st = bi.times(lp).times(lv)

  // read matrix into float array and transpose.
```

Interestingly, the shadow texture matrix also had to be transposed.

Still, the resulting image is shown below - it has artifacts. Question is - how to get rid of them?

[image: scene with artifacts]

EDIT:

Apparently, the problem is erroneous self-shadowing.

I realized this while reading the suggested link - thanks for the pointer!

However, the links suggests adjusting the near and far planes - this is not the solution.
The solution is to adjust the scaling factor of the depth matrix. To avoid peter-panning, the scale in the z-axis should be as big as possible, but less than `1.f`:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE)
glLoadIdentity()
glScalef(1.f, 1.f, 0.9999f)
```

The result:

[image: scene, no artifacts]

I figured it out while going through [this example](http://kenai.com/projects/jogl/sources/jogl-demos-git/content/src/demos/hwShadowmapsSimple/HWShadowmapsSimple.java?rev=2d5f1650af2b64f7a8d25842b2b95192b3e4a4e9).

Comment: Microsoft has an excellent article about improving the quality of your shadow maps: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416324%28v=vs.85%29.aspx Jump to "Shadow Acne and Erroneous Self-Shadowing". P.S. It would have been better if you had edited your original question.

Comment: Thank you for your link, judging from the screenshots there, they attack this problem - I will read this in more detail. I thought about editing the question, but I my thinking was that transposing the matrix might in fact be part of an answer.

Comment: Their advice is just - make sure that near and far clipping planes are as tight as possible. I think I already made them pretty tight - bringing the far plane further away or the near plane closer results in parts of the depth buffer being at full 1.0 or 0.0. So I think there must be some other solution.